# Strange error and other strange behavior with generic unit of measure structs in F#

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I have this type:

```
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'u> =
    struct
        val x:float32<'u>
        val y:float32<'u>
        val z:float32<'u>
    end

    new(x, y, z) = { x = x; y = y; z = z }
```

When I try to make a default instance, it gives me a strange error that I couldn't find any information on Google about:

> Error  5   The default, zero-initializing constructor of a struct type may only be used if all the fields of the struct type admit default initialization

So okay, I can just use the default constructor to set everything to `0` with. Or not.

```
let f = Vector3(0.f<N>, 0.f<N>, 0.f<N>)
```

Gives me an error:

> Error  1   This expression was expected to have type     float32     but here has type     float32

This only seems to happen when I use this instance in a subsequent calculation; otherwise, it correctly resolves the type of `f` as being `Vector3<N>`. Giving the constructor the type, as in `Vector3<N>(...)` seems to also solve the problem, which is really strange.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you define N?  Because what you have above (setting everything to 0) works fine for me - or maybe the problem is in your subsequent calculation?

Comment: @David N is under `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.SI`, which I believe is in the PowerPack. The calculation works fine with a record format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be something wrong elsewhere in your code. If you reset F# Interactive, open a new empty F# Script file and paste the following code (and then run it in FSI), then everything works just fine for me:

```
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'u> =
    struct
        val x:float32<'u>
        val y:float32<'u>
        val z:float32<'u>
    end
    new(x, y, z) = { x = x; y = y; z = z }

[<Measure>] type N    
let f = Vector3(0.f<N>, 0.f<N>, 0.f<N>)
```

I would recommend writing the code using implicit constructor syntax which is more succinct and more idiomatic F# (the `struct .. end` declaration is still allowed, but it has been used mainly in old versions of F#). Default constructor doesn't seem to work in this scenario, but you can use static member:

```
[<Struct>]
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'u>(x:float32<'u>, y:float32<'u>, z:float32<'u>) =
    member this.X = x    
    member this.Y = y
    member this.Z = z
    static member Empty : Vector3<'u> = Vector3(0.f<_>, 0.f<_>, 0.f<_>)

[<Measure>] type N

let f1 = Vector3<N>.Empty
let f2 = Vector3(0.f<N>, 0.f<N>, 0.f<N>) 
f1.X + f2.X
```

Comment: Could you expand on the performance discussion Tomas. I kinda stand on Ankur's side of the story. I'm pretty sure if the benchmark was run with 5-8 fields the structs approach would suffer. The point about the XBox/Compact GC holds if that is indeed the target platform.

Comment: @David - I didn't read the entire discussion under Ankur's answer. Performance always depends on the specific scenario - adding and removing the `Struct` attribute is the easiest way to find out :-). In general, structs are probably better for few fields if you need to create lots of them (especially if they are stored e.g. in an array).

Comment: Regarding the link that Ankur posted (stack-allocation is an implemetnation detail) - if the type is immutable, then it doesn't matter whether it is allocated on the heap or the stack. This is great, because you can write your code and then add/remov `Struct` attribute and see what works better - it doesn't affect the behavior, just performance. Especially with arrays, it does matter though, because array of structs can be allocated as single continuous block of memory.

Comment: @David The main rule is that if a struct ever needs to be boxed (i.e. cast to `object`), then it's converted to something that behaves like a class -- so it's in fact slower than a reference type. This doesn't happen as often anymore, as generics alleviate that need. Also, structs are said to perform best at under 32bytes -- but my experience has been that they can be quite a bit larger and still be faster than classes in the big picture even on PC, because they don't stress the garbage collector as much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the Default Value attribute for val fields:

```
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'u> =
    struct
        [<DefaultValue(false)>] val mutable x:float32<'u>
        [<DefaultValue(false)>] val mutable y:float32<'u>
        [<DefaultValue(false)>] val mutable z:float32<'u>
    end
    member X.Init(x,y,z) = 
        X.x <- x
        X.y <- y
        X.z <- z
```

Or use record types:

```
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'u> = { x : float32<'u>; y : float32<'u> ; z : float32<'u> }
[<Measure>] type N
let v = { x = 10.0F<N>; y = 10.0F<N>; z = 10.0F<N> }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'u> =
    struct
        val x:float32<'u>
        val y:float32<'u>
        val z:float32<'u>
        new(X, Y, Z) = { x = X; y = Y; z = Z }
    end
```

Comment: Bleh, now it says "Extraneous fields have been given values" in the constructor.

Comment: If you don't want mutable, I think u can use Record types

Comment: I'd love to use Records, but they pressure the garbage collector considerably.

Comment: @Rei: do you have some information concerning records and the GC? I'm interessted in those things and have not heard of those performances issues with records yet.

Comment: Records are simple classes with read only properties, I am not sure how they pressure the GC

Comment: @Ankur Tuples are classes, which are reference types, which means they must be created on the heap. Structs on the other hand are value types, which means the GC doesn't need to deal with them.

Comment: @CKoenig -- Scroll down to "designing with ValueTypes" in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx). The information is somewhat outdated though; the introduction of generics in C# 2 has made it so that struct types don't need to be boxed.

Comment: @Rei - This is a very general misconception made by developers that struct are allocated at stack and classes are at heap. Please refer : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: @Ankur Conceptually, yeah, it's better to think of structs as being "pass-by-value" and classes as being "pass-by-reference", but when performance comes into question, the memory allocation details are rather important.

Comment: Well. I would suggest you try to run the app with both types and churn out some performance number as this is very subjective until you really find those numbers

Comment: @Ankur I did -- with records, I can manage about 1,500,000 particles per second (each particle has a bunch of vector operations). With structs, I can get about 2,100,000. Also, the performance implications of using reference types as opposed to value types is a well-known issue. I don't think it's very subjective.

Comment: Yes - that what I thought as well. Thanks for the answers. Good to hear that it's not a problem with records but maybe with classes in general :| ... I guess I stick by my usual priciple: "optimice *if* need arises"

Comment: @CKoenig Yep definitely. I started this project with using records for vectors, but it quickly became clear that structs, even immutable, are *much* faster -- which is pretty important for a game, especially if it's to run on Xbox/WP7, which have notoriously slow garbage collection. Unfortunately, struct syntax in F# differs from record syntax more than it should seem to need to, so this is one of those situations where I have to think about optimization ahead of time.

Comment: @Ankur Now we're missing the default constructor again... it's pretty much the same as the code in my question. Thanks for all the effort so far by the way.

Comment: If you need default constructor then you need to have mutable values otherwise how would you set values

Comment: @Ankur Well, the origin vector is kind of a common occurrence in math and physics.